# Origin and usage of "graveyard slot"

Tags: etymology, popular-refrains

The curious expression ***[graveyard slot](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/graveyard-slot)*** has two main connotations:

> - (television) the hours from late night until early morning when the number of people watching television is at its lowest. (Collins)

and:.

> - Speakers and trainers often refer to the ***[“graveyard slot](http://alanmatthewstraining.com/2012/06/how-to-handle-the-graveyard-slot/)***”. By this they usually mean the first session after lunch when people are presumed to be a bit sleepy after eating.(alanmatthewstraining.com)

According to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graveyard%20slot&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgraveyard%20slot%3B%2Cc0)*** the expression is from the early '70s

There is an earlier and similar expression ***[graveyard shift/watch](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/graveyard-shift.html)*** which means:

> - The Graveyard Shift, or Graveyard Watch, was the name coined for the work shift of the early morning, typically midnight until 8am. ***The name originated in the USA at the latter end of the 1800s.***
> - There's no evidence at all that it had anything directly to do with watching over graveyards, merely that the shifts took place in the middle of the night, when the ambience was quiet and lonely. (The Phrase Finder)

Questions:

- is there any evidence (apart from the obvious similarities) that "graveyard slot" derives from "graveyard shift"?
- was the saying "graveyard slot" an AmE originally?
- is it now mainly a BrE expression as ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graveyard%20slot%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cgraveyard%20slot%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgraveyard%20slot%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgraveyard%20slot%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)*** appears to suggest?

Comment: Isn't this a near exact duplicate of another question from about 3 days back???

Comment: @HotLicks - no this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Was the other one yours?  Why was it deleted?

Comment: This is the only question of its kind in the site. Do you have an answer?

Comment: I know it's the only one, as do you.  The other one was deleted for some reason.

Comment: @HotLicks - it is up to the  OP to keep or  delete a question without answers. I think the current one is better (more research) than the previous one.

Comment: I can't imagine this is anything but a combination of *graveyard shift* + *slot* used to indicate a precisely-bounded slice of time (where something can be fit in, or slotted in; in this case, that thing is a shift of work).

Comment: "Graveyard" gets attached to a lot of things to mean dead or no activity and a late night time period.  Graveyard slot: late night time period and no viewership.  Graveyard shift: late night time period when most people are asleep or inactive (the rest of the word is dead).  One term wasn't derived from the other.  They are both usages of "graveyard".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "graveyard slot," with the television scheduling meaning, appeared at least as early as 1968, in this piece from the entertainment section of *The Chicago Tribune*.  This article contained no mention of "graveyard shift" or any other explanation of the term, though a casual reader could probably understand it through context if it was a figurative use.

[image]

- [Clay Gowrin, *Chicago Tribune* 20 Mar 1968](https://www.newspapers.com/image/197030903/?terms=%22graveyard%2Bslot%22) (paywall)

Whether or not "graveyard slot" derives from "graveyard shift," the two have been used in similar ways.  In the *Asheville Citizen-Times*, a feature piece on a late night DJ started with the headline:

> **Fred Brown: Bringing Life to the Graveyard Shift**

In the content, the piece uses the term "graveyard slot," with a definition included.

> A staffer at top-rated WWNC-AM since 1969, he's worked radio's most challenging shift for almost three years -- the **graveyard slot**, 11 p.m.-5:30 a.m., five nights (or mornings) a week.

- [Tony Kiss, *Asheville Citizen-Times* 29 Apr 1988](https://www.newspapers.com/image/198964843/?terms=%22graveyard%2Bslot%22) (paywall)

The headline might have used "graveyard shift" because it was a more prevalent term and easier to understand for casual readers, or because Fred Brown was *working* the "graveyard shift," while *filling* the "graveyard slot."

Either way, other sources appear to use "graveyard shift" with a television meaning, so to that extent, both appear to be acceptable for describing television scheduling.  This was done as early as 1972 in a widely syndicated piece by the Associated Press, retrieved here:

> The show is NBC's brave new hour for insomniacs, students, people who leave work at midnight and other assorted night owls who heretorfore have made do with ancient film epics on **television's graveyard shift**.

- [*The Manhattan Mercury* 07 Sep 1972](https://www.newspapers.com/image/10863618/?terms=%22television%2Bgraveyard%2Bshift%22) (paywall)

---

> So why would NBC schedule it for 10 p.m. EDT, the Saturday **TV graveyard shift**?
>
> That hour is generally reserved for documentaries and reruns of the lame-duck "NBC Magazine," while young fans are asleep.

- [*Hattiesburg American* 06 Aug 1982](https://www.newspapers.com/image/276984812/?terms=%22TV%2Bgraveyard%2Bshift%22) (paywall)

---

As early as 1962, the term "graveyard shift" was used referring to the late hours of radio reporting, which predates the uses of "graveyard slot" above.

[image]

- [*The Press Democrat* 14 Jan 1962](https://www.newspapers.com/image/282694284/?terms=%22graveyard%2Bshift%22%2B%2B%2Btelevision)